# Interpreting the second derivative

Tags: calculus

If a function is decreasing and but concave up, would you say it is decreasing at an increasing rate?  It seems misleading.  What is a better way to say this?

Comment: The rate of decrease is decreasing as the derivative is increasing.

Comment: Yes, it is decreasing, but "slowing down". Think the left half of the parabola $y=x^2$ for a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should say "it is decreasing at a decreasing rate". Why? Because the rate of decreasing is the negative of the rate of change. In symbols, if $f' < 0$ and $f'' > 0$ then $f$ is decreasing at the rate $-f'$, which is decreasing. If that is confusing, then it's better to stick with the mathematical notation.

Answer (score 0):

It's decreasing at a rate whose magnitude is decreasing.